# How to close a thread in multithread environment java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

So, my server app causing a huge cpu usage averaging about 95%. I think the reason is it keep spawning new thread but not closing it. how am I suppose to close a thread when any of this happen: refresh page, logout, browser closed.

My code is more or less like this for server part.

ThreadedEchoServer.java

```
public class ThreadedEchoServer {
    // using port 2000
    static final int PORT = 2000;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
            }

            // new thread for a client
            new EchoThread(socket).start();
        }
    }
}
```

EchoThread.java

```
/*
Class for java server to accept incoming stream
and create a new thread to save log file data in server
*/
public class EchoThread extends Thread {
    protected Socket socket;

    public EchoThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.socket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        /*Create a File*/
        int i = 1;
        try {
            File directory = new File("F:/temp/tmplog/" + getDate());
            if(!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdir();
            }

            String fileName = "F:/temp/tmplog/" + getDate() + "/" + getDateTime() + ".txt";
            File file = new File(fileName);

            //Double Make Sure it create the file
            while(file.exists()) {
                file = new File(fileName + "." + i);
                i++;
            }
            FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fis);
            System.setOut(out);


            while (true) {
              try {
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "US-ASCII"));

                String line = null;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println(line);
                }
              } catch (IOException exception) {
                // Just handle next request.
              } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                  try {
                    socket.close();
                  } catch (IOException ignored) {
                  }
                }
                fis.close();
              }
            }


        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
```

This server app basicly will open a new and write a log file for every thread/client. I think the problem is I do not close the thread after use. that's why it just keep spawning new thread.. Any help?

Comment: Can you put a `println` to see if it leaves this loop:             `while(file.exists()) ...` ? And another one at the end of the `run` method to see if the threads exit?

Comment: Sure - debug the EchoThread and find out what happens when the client closes its connection. Does the 'catch (IOException exception)' happen?  If so, what do you do in there?  Should there be a return so that the finally can execute, close the socket and exit the thread?

Comment: @MartinJames the part that I'm not sure is whether the thread will exit while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {}, since it will keep waiting for new stream. I was wondering what happen if the user refresh the page, or close the browser? will it automaticly exit that loop, or how can I make sure it exit the loop.

Comment: I don't know.  I would expect the recv(), or whatever, that is wrapped by readLine() to return 0 if the browser closes the connection.  I would think that then the readLine() should throw something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you're looking for, you can just use a timeout to handle this situation.
When the timeout expires, you'll just terminate the thread.

EchoThread

```
/*
Class for java server to accept incoming stream
and create a new thread to save log file data in server
*/
public class EchoThread extends Thread {
    protected Socket socket;

    public EchoThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.socket = clientSocket;
        this.socket.setSoTimeout(10000); //Sets timeout to 10 seconds
    }

    public void run() {
        /*Create a File*/
        int i = 1;
        try {
            File directory = new File("F:/temp/tmplog/" + getDate());
            if(!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdir();
            }

            String fileName = "F:/temp/tmplog/" + getDate() + "/" + getDateTime() + ".txt";
            File file = new File(fileName);

            //Double Make Sure it create the file
            while(file.exists()) {
                file = new File(fileName + "." + i);
                i++;
            }
            FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fis);
            System.setOut(out);


            while (true) {
              try {
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "US-ASCII"));

                String line = null;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println(line);
                }
              } catch (IOException exception) {
                // Just handle next request.
              } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                  try {
                    socket.close();
                  } catch (IOException ignored) {
                  }
                }
                fis.close();
              }
            }


        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        } catch (SocketException e) { //Exception thrown by timeout
            socket.close(); //We close the socket
            this.stop(); //We stop the thread
        }
    }
```

Comment: with your solution, it will work, but what happen if the user just put the page on, and an hour later, or two hour later, they suddenly want to send something, that means there will be no log being written, since the thread already closed. is there anyway to prevent this? beside change the timeout to an hour or more. The best solution if it's even possible is, detect if the user navigate away from the applet such as logout, refresh or go to other page, and close the thread only during that event. any example? Thank you

Comment: You should look for an `onClose()` method or something like this, but I don't know if Java Applets have such method!